# Remove very first row in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

After doing some data preparation my df looks like (0 1 0 1 and 0 0 1 1 shown like  column names):

```
df = 

0  1  0  1
0  0  1  1

11 22 33 44
55 66 77 88
```

How to remove the row of `0 1 0 1`?

---

Done code before:

```
df = df.stack().str.split(' ', expand=True).unstack()
df = df.sort_index(axis=1, level=1)
```

Comment: just `df.drop(0)`

Comment: did not work out @yatu

Comment: Please provide the code which you worked on ?

Comment: @yatu You meant `df  = df.drop(0)`

Comment: check the edited question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.droplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.droplevel.html) because there is `MultiIndex` in columns:

```
df = df.sort_index(axis=1, level=1).droplevel(0, axis=1)
```

Or for oldier versions of pandas [`MultiIndex.droplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.droplevel.html):

```
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(0)
```

Comment: @MamedMamedov - no, only you post your code, so my idea about `MultiIndex` was approved.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df = df.iloc[1:]
```

It'll return a new df without the first row.

Reference:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html

Answer (score 1):

df.drop(0) Will return a DataFrame without the removed row. (Works for columns, labels, elements...)